# Generic Classes Misunderstanding

Tags: c#

Coming from php I'm new to C#.
I want to create a Store, that keeps all data in an organised but modular/generic structure. Therefore I have a class `Store` that gets data from an api and should store that to a local RecordStore:

```
class Store
{
     public static T FindRecord<T>(Type ModelType, int id)
     {
            RestClient rClient = new RestClient();
            Debug.WriteLine("making request to: " + ModelType.Name.ToLower() + "/" + id);
            string response = rClient.makeRequest(ModelType.Name.ToLower()+"/"+id);
            JObject Payload = JObject.Parse(response);
            T model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Payload[ModelType.Name.ToLower()].ToString());
            // all good til there
            // but HERE'S THE PROBLEM:
            RecordStore.PushItem(ModelType, model);
            return model;
     }
}

class RecordStore
{
    protected static List<BaseModel> Models;
    // I can't do that:
    // protected static List<T> Models;

    public static void PushItem<T>(Type ModelType, T Item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("pushing ModelType: "+ModelType.ToString());
        Models.Add(Item); // na, that won't work: "Converting from "T" to "BaseModel" not possible
    }
}
```

All this is called from Main like this:

```
Production Production = Store.FindRecord<Production>(typeof(Production), id: 3);
```

Production is a simple class that extends BaseModel, nothing special there. Just some properties which describe the model.
RestClient is another simple class that calls my Api to get the data as json.

So, **the question is**: What do I misunderstand with generic properties/methods? What am I doing wrong? Is there a simple fix to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: For the generic `T` type, you could add a constraint `where T : BaseModel`, but I can't tell if that's what you actually want or not

Comment: @PatrickRoberts that's what TheGeneral answered later, I'll try it, thanks!

Comment: The big difference between PHP and C# for me is strong typisation. Compile time checks of types are integral to avoiding all number of hard to debug followup issues. There are some downsides to strong typisation and prior to Generics, the **only** way around it was to abandon it entirely, usually using Object as the type. We still see that pattern in all Event Handlers. You either write a function for every single type imaginable - including ones that do not exist when writing the class. Or you use Object, abandoning all type safety.

Comment: Generics try to be more of a "happy middle ground". A related concept might be native C++ Templates, but it does not fit fully. With a generic you do not need to specify **wich** specific type will be used. Just that **a** specific type will be provided at compile time. And that means the compiler can do all those important compile time typechecks. You can write a function or class that accepts the class "HumptyDumpteysLeftToe" when being told so, without having to make a class that just accepts any object and thus breaks all type safety entirely. You get "the best of both worlds".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is mainly constraints. However take a look at the following refactor

```
public class BaseModel
{
    ///
}

public class RecordStore
{
   protected static List<BaseModel> Models;

   public static void PushItem<T>(T item)
      where T : BaseModel
   {
      var modelType = typeof(T);
      Console.WriteLine("pushing ModelType: " + modelType.ToString());
      Models.Add(item);
   }
}

public class Store
{
   public static T FindRecord<T>(int id)
      where T : BaseModel
   {
      var modelType = typeof(T);
      var rClient = new RestClient();
      Debug.WriteLine($"making request to: {modelType.Name.ToLower()}/{id}");
      var response = rClient.makeRequest($"{modelType.Name.ToLower()}/{id}");
      var payload = JObject.Parse(response);

      var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(
         payload[modelType.Name.ToLower()]
           .ToString());

      RecordStore.PushItem(model);

      return model;
   }
}
```

**Further reading**

[Constraints on type parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

> Constraints inform the compiler about the capabilities a type argument
>   must have. Without any constraints, the type argument could be any
>   type. The compiler can only assume the members of Object, which is the
>   ultimate base class for any .NET type